# Why am I getting peer authentication failed error when trying to connect using psycopg2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

So I have a successful install of Postgres on Ubuntu and am trying to do some basic connection and creating a table in a db using another username other than the default (postgres) and coming up short. From what I can gather I think it may have something to do with permissions? What I want is to be able to use some superuser other than postgres to create tables and do stuff.

"psql example3" and "\l" shows the example3 db was created successfully. I now have a list of databases include the default postgres, template0, template1 and example3 all with owner as postgres. What I run into problems then is running demoscript.py gives a fatal "peer authentication failed for user 'thisuser'"

```
#Create the db and user with superuser permissions
sudo -u postgres -i
createdb example3
createuser --interactive --pwprompt
#role:thisuser
#pwd:thispass
#superuser?:Y
```

```
#demoscript.py
import psycopg2 
connection = psycopg2.connect('dbname=example3 user=thisuser password=thispass')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todos;')

cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE todos(
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        description VARCHAR NOT NULL
        );
''')
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Expected result is that the todos table should show as created after looking for it in the example3 db. But I just get the fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't specify a host in your connection, it tries to connect via Unix sockets. By default, PostgreSQL is set up to use peer authentication on those, which means it compares the PostgreSQL username to the currently logged in OS user. If you change your connection to:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect('dbname=example3 user=thisuser password=thispass host=localhost')
```

that should cause it to use the authentication settings for TCP/IP connections, which default to password authentication on most systems I've used.

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct in assuming that peer authentication requires something like "sudo -u postgres python demoscript.py"? And also, do you happen to know off the top of your head what happens if a host is specified but no password is provided (ie. the password field is just left blank during the user creation process)

Comment: That command would work if you are connecting to the database as the user "postgres". Peer authentication compares the Postgres user name to the OS user running the program which is trying to connect, and allowing access if the two are the same.  As for creating a user without a password, I'm not sure what the result would be, but I suspect that connections using password authentication would fail. For more information about configuring how postgres authenticates users, see [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)